# Check if emoji character

Tags: java, emoji

I have a Java servlet which accepts text from mobile devices. I need to check each character and check if it is a normal text or if it is an emoji before I insert it into my database. The problem I am having is how do I detect if a character is emoji?

Comment: how do you define your emojis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok simple example defined private string emoji regex.

```
 private final String regex = "([\\u20a0-\\u32ff\\ud83c\\udc00-\\ud83d\\udeff\\udbb9\\udce5-\\udbb9\\udcee])";
```

variable with test sentence

```
test = "josh stevens is the best "
```

you can use a `Matcher` to find any group in the test string that matches the `regex`.

```
Matcher matchEmo = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(test);
while (matchEmo.find()) {
    System.out.println(matchEmo.group());
}
```

this will print the emoji which matches them in string.
Hope this helps.