# Android emojis char size

Tags: android, emoji

I'm currently developing a keyboard for android , and i found out some emojis take 2 chars and some take 1 char ,

Is there a way to differ between the two if they are in a string ?

Comment: you really need to detect a sequence of 2 characters in a string to replace them with emojis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i managed to solve this issue by using this lib

https://github.com/vdurmont/emoji-java

in there , there is a isEmoji(string)

```
   String currentTextStr = currentText.toString().substring(currentText.length() - 2);
   Log.e("emojicon",""+EmojiManager.isEmoji(currentTextStr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently seeing the pattern - if emoji doesn't have browser version of it, then that libs `isEmoji()`function fails to recognize emojis, like Nr. 927, Nr. 938: http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html